# ERC677 transferAndCall

Tags: chainlink, transfer, calldata, data, erc-677

i want to send some **LINK** to a `contract B` from a `contract A`, and in the same function call a function in `contract B`, im using `transferAndCall(address _to, uint _value, bytes _data)` function in the `LinkToken` contract, **my question is** : what should i put in the **_data** parametre and if you can give an exemple on how to do it so it can be more apparent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just transferring tokens I don't think you need to put anything in the data parameter.

The data parameter is only used to pass additional parameters to indicate what the intention of the transfer is if a contract allows transfers for multiple reasons.

Comment: what value should i put ? i can't let it empty

Comment: 0x00000000000000000000000000000000

does this work?

Comment: yes it does, thank you